Lebesgue measure simple property. Seems intuitevely true but can't formalise a proof.
Consider the usual Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f,g \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be two arbitrary functions that satisfy
$$ | \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : g(x) \neq h(x) \} | > 0 \quad \text{ and }\quad | \{x \in \mathbb R^n : h(x) \neq 0\}| = 0, $$
where $|A|$ stands for the Lebesgue measure of the subset $A \subset \mathbb R^n$.
GOAL. My aim is to prove that, under these hypothesis, there holds
$$ | \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : g(x) \neq 0\}| > 0. $$
My attempt. Intuitively, this implication seems true but I am having a hard time proving it formally.  I appreciate any hints so that I can begin my reasoning.
Thanks for any help in advance.

${ x \in \mathbb R^n : g(x) \neq h(x) } \subset { x \in \mathbb R^n : g(x) \neq 0) } \cup { x \in \mathbb R^n : h(x) \neq 0 }$

@geetha290krm Thanks, I was able to formalise it based on your hint :)
